# Combining だけ and 位

Tags: grammar

I'm aware that だけ can be used to say only. For example:

```
二年{にねん}だけ
```

which means "only two years".
I'm also aware that 位{ぐらい} can be used to signify approximation. For example:

```
 二年位
```

which means "about two years".

So my question is can I combine both? Is `二年位だけ` correct? Does it mean it's only been about two years?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can safely say 2年ぐらいだけ ("only about two years"). Here ぐらい means "approximately".

> 2年ぐらいだけ日本語を勉強した。 I studied Japanese only for about two years.